# How to resume data download in objective c?

Tags: core-data

I am downloading some data and internet connection breaks in between,how to resume download from current state in core data model?

Answer (score 0):

The core data model and the download have nothing to do with each other. You would have to distinguish these steps:

1. Make a download request.
2. The download ends with success or error.
3. Handle the data - e.g. store it in core data.

   - if finished successfully, you are done
   - if not continue
4. Notice that you can download again.
5. Form a new download request, requesting only the missing data from the server
6. Go to step 2.

Step 1 will be handled with a `NSURLRequest`.
Step 2 can be caught in the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods.
Step 3 is should be routine if you were successful. If not, you would have to analyze your data object to see what you can salvage and save.
Step 4 can be accomplished with the `Reachability` class. Check Apple's sample code.
Step 5 requires that your server can handle the selective data requests.

There are a lot of details to the single steps. Best scavenge on stackoverflow and consult the documentation to code the individual steps. I hope this scheme is helping you to sort things out.

Comment: How to re-initate downloading from current state,if I have downloaded 40% of entire  data I want to download rest 60% only.What are the steps for maintaining percent of downloaded data.In my data model there is a complex data model having many to many relationships and downloading process consist multiple http request saving data in multiple tables.

Comment: How about keeping track of successful download with a `BOOL`. Iterate through the objects and queue new download requests where the download was not successful. I do this slightly differently in one of my projects, with an array of download requests.